# Barcode scanning does not work when running from XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, barcode

I'm trying to implement barcode scanning in my Swift app using `AVFoundation` as described in [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/) (and others I found on the net).

I'm using an IPhone 5 and an IPhone SE to test this. I can see the camera image alright, but recognition only works if I don't start the app from XCode, but by directly tapping the app's icon on the device.

I could not find any information on this - why is it that the devices do not recognize barcodes when the app is run from XCode? Is there anything I need to configure?

Comment: does the Xcode console give any helpful hints when you launch the app and/or try to scan a barcode?  Also, what iOS versions do your iPhones run?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Not at the machine right now, will check tonight. Both iPhones run the latest iOS 10.

Comment: @KiritModi To my real amazement your example works as expected also when debugging in XCode. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar. Thanks you brother...